# Can I change 'philosophical' to 'philosophy'?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Can I/we change 'philosophical' to 'philosophy'?

There are 5 questions tagged philosophical but I think philosophy is a (grammatically) better tag for them.

**edit**: I have done this now.

Comment: `philosophy` seems more consistent with mathoverflow, where the tag [`math-philosophy`](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/math-philosophy) is used.